# How much power does the Solar Great Works provide?

Tags: simcity-2013

As the title states I would like to know exactly what I can expect to receive from finishing the Solar Great Works in Simcity. How much power can it provide to the surrounding regions and what is the basic cost? Is it enough and cost effective enough to utilize it for all power requirements for all of the cities or is it meant to only be supplemental?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

~2500 MW

Compare this to a nuclear plant, which produces 200 MW